# convert image to maptiles using gdal2tiles

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, gdal, tiling

I need to split an image into tiles that fit for map in different zoom levels.
I tried with Gal2tiles but I was not able to get tiles.

I am using PNG image for splitting to tiles.

Comment: Thanks kryger for the edit.

Answer (score 3):

I developed GDAL2Tiles couple of years back as a student project. It is a command-line utility with available manual http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html and a step-by-step tutorials online - one of them made by people from Google: https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/raster

In case you are not familiar with command-line you can easily try the MapTiler http://www.maptiler.com/ - the significantly improved and rewritten tool for creating map tiles. MapTiler comes with a user-friendly graphical user interface and is easy to install - on Windows, Mac or Linux.

See a video tutorial for a demonstration of usage:

[image: MapTiler Google Maps Overlays]

http://youtu.be/eJxdCe9CNYg